# Retrieve row info of a dynamic table using Jquery when user clicks on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Jquery. I am learning the things one by one. my requirement is to create a dynamic jquery datatable.So I created in the following way:
The variable `formattedCKEY` is a dynamic value that I am using for generating the table id's dynamically

```
var issueTableId = "issuetable_"+formattedCKEY;
var $issuetable = $("
<table  id='" + issueTableId + "' class='stripe nowrap'  style='position:relative; top:0px; width:95%;'></table>
");
$issuetable.append('
<thead>
   ').children('thead')
   .append('
   <tr />
      ').children('tr')
      .append('
      <th nowrap>Select</th>
      '+
      '
      <th nowrap>Priority</th>
      ' +
      '
      <th nowrap>Issue ID</th>
      ' +
      var $tbody = $issuetable.append('
<tbody />
   ').children('tbody');
   $.each(cases, function () {
   $tbody.append('
   <tr />
      ').children('tr:last')
      .append('
      <td nowrap><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;</td>
      ')
      .append('
      <td nowrap>' + $(this).find("PRTY").text() + '</td>
      ')
      .append(sourceRow)
      .append('
      <td nowrap>' + $(this).find("ISSUEID").text() + '</td>
      ');
      });
```

Here I am struggling with selecting the row information when the user click on that particular row. can anybody help me out how to do this when there are dynamic table id's?

I have tried with following code so far:

```
 //DataTables aplies style and behavior to <table>
 var table = $("#" + issueTableId).DataTable({
     "scrollY": 315, // inconsistent IE7/other
     "scrollX": true,
     "searching": false,
     "paging": false,
     "info": false
 });

 table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
     var row = this.row(rowIdx).node();
     // add contextMenu to each rows onclick
     $(row).click(displayResultslistPopup);
     // add onclick for each rows checkbox
     $(row).find('input:checkbox').click(function(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         $('#SAcheckBox').prop('checked', false);
     });
     // use presence of the attachmentImage.png to add jquery click event for td:
     $(row).find('td:has(img)').click(function(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
         issueAttachmentAttachmentLookUp(id);
     });
 });
```

But somehow `table.rows().every()` is not working for me. My intention is to register the click event on table row and retrieve the necessary row information.

Comment: have you tried anything from your end? what exact information you are looking for?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, Thanks for the response. I have added the piece of code that I tried to the question itself. Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind a function to your row click, you can use click() function of jquery and pass a callback function.

```
$tbody.append('<tr />')
    .click(rowClickCallback)
    .children('tr:last')....

function rowClickCallback(e) {
    console.log(e.target); // It returns the TD which user clicked
    console.log(e.target.parentElement); // It returns the TR which user clicked
}
```

Comment: That's awesome!! but what if I want only specific column value in that row? For example  `Issue ID` column value of the user clicked row.

Comment: You can get the specific TD from the TR. For example if you aim the third TD on the clicked TR, you can get it with `$('td:eq(2)',e.target.parentElement)`. Here `:eq(index)` returns your specific child by its index.

Comment: I think I am confused. I need the text value of the column `Issue ID` of the user clicked row. Let's assume the index of that is 2. Could you please tell me how to get that?

Comment: `function rowClickCallback(e) {
    var issue_id = $('td:eq(2)',e.target.parentElement).text();
    alert('This row ISSUE_ID is ' + issue_id);
}`

Comment: But I am getting the Object,  not the text that I require. Any clue now?

Comment: `e.target` is giving me the  required `td`. But only problem is that it is returning the cell value that is clicked on the row. In my case, I always require only one cell value whose column header is` Issue ID`

Comment: I wrote an example for your issue:
[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/prc0mputing/pen/zJYQOE)

Comment: Hey! That worked like a charm!!! .Thanks much dude... +1 for your support.